# Parallax effect on <script> block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to apply a parallax effect to a script block which rotates images around on a pageload basis. It used to work when the content of the HTML div was a static `<img>`. Because the Javascript looks for `$('#parallaxical img').css` which isn't being used anymore due to the replacement of the static `<img>` with `Randomize()` my Parallax effect does not work anymore. I have tried changing around a great deal of things without success.

How do I let the "Header Parallax Effect" script look for the new dynamic `<script>` block instead of the previous `<img>`?

HTML:

```
<div class="inner" id="parallaxical">
     <script type="text/javascript">Randomize()</script>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parallaxical {
  width: 100%; height: 300px; overflow: hidden; display: block; position: absolute;
}
#parallaxical img {
  width: 100%; height: auto; min-height: 300px !important; min-width: 1280px !important;
}
#parallaxical h2 {
  margin: -20px 0px 0px; top: 50%; width: 100%; text-align: center; position: absolute;
}
#parallaxical a {
  padding: 0px 20px; color: rgb(221, 221, 221); letter-spacing: 1px; font-size: 24px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
#parallaxical a:hover {
  color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
}
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
/*Header parallax effect
======================================================*/
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      var window_scroll_position = $(this).scrollTop();
      var parallax_value = window_scroll_position/4;

      $('#parallaxical img').css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'translateY('+ parallax_value +'px)',
        '-moz-transform': 'translateY('+ parallax_value +'px)',
        '-o-transform': 'translateY('+ parallax_value +'px)',
        '-ms-transform': 'translateY('+ parallax_value +'px)',
        'transform': 'translateY('+ parallax_value +'px)'
      });
    });
    $('#parallaxical a').click(function(e){
      var title = $(this).attr('title');
      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Takeovers', 'Clickthrough to Page', title]);
    });
  });
})(jQuery)

/*Header rotate
======================================================*/
function Randomize() {
    var images = new Array("images/banner/banner1.jpg","images/banner/banner2.jpg","images/banner/banner3.jpg","images/banner/banner4.jpg");
    var imageNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    document.getElementById("parallaxical").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + images[imageNum] + "')";
    document.getElementById("parallaxical").style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
}

window.onload = Randomize;
```

Comment: In an attempt to make my previous question more clear I rephrased the original question. The answer on the previous question however has been integrated in the 'Header rotate' script block and thus accepted.

Comment: your css is targetting an img tag. but your Randomize() function doesn't create an img. It simply sets the background-image of the container. Have it create an image inside the container and all will be fine

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Could you perhaps give a (small) example?

Comment: document.createElement('img'); https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement

Comment: Alright, I've been playing around with this for a while now, but I can't seem to grasp the concept. Losing quite a lot of hair for my age over this. 

I suppose I have to remove the document.getElementById lines and insert a document.createElement(img) instead of those lines. Question is; How do I fill this new element with an image from the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
var Randomize = (function() {
    var imageDirectory = 'images/banner/';
    var images = new Array(
        "banner1.jpg",
        "banner2.jpg",
        "banner3.jpg",
        "banner4.jpg"
    );

    return function() {
        //get a random number
        var imageNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
        //create the image
        var image = document.createElement('img');
        image.src = imageDirectory + images[imageNum];
        //add it to the containing element
        document.getElementById('parallaxical').appendChild(image);
    }

}());
```

**changes**

- I wrapped the code inside an iife.
- created a imageDirectory variable. Looks nicer.

Comment: Awesome! Love the way you cleaned the code up to begin with. Perfect execution.